# Multiple views in one ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface

I am trying to make one large view controller which contains multiple buttons and other views.

One view (also contains list of buttons) is hidden and it could be shown on button click.

How can I make such a large scene, as in Xcode I'm not able to see anything larger than scene size. Here is screen shot of one of my attempts:

[image]

I tried my best to find some tutorial, but without success.

Comment: use scrollview please refer this link  https://www.appcoda.com/uiscrollview-introduction/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put scroll view onto your view controller, and put all your buttons onto it. To make it in interface builder set your view controllers size in interface builder. It will not affect at running but will make your controller larger, for building large scenes in interface builder. To do so, select your view controller scene, and at size inspector( at right utilities pane) switch simulated size from fixed, to whatever you need. Again, it will not affect at runtime size. Only for interface builder